# Endless Fetch Loop Despite useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-usecallback

I have an issue with my React Native App where I have a URL fetch request to return data when a tab is loaded, but for some reason there is an endless loop between between the callback happening and the try statement, but it doesn't reach the rest of the code and return the object. Am I using useCallback incorrectly?

Logs:

```
 LOG  ~~ fetchData - try ~~
 LOG  ~~ fetchData ~~
 LOG  ~~ fetchData - try ~~
 LOG  ~~ fetchData ~~
 LOG  ~~ fetchData - try ~~
```

Fetch Code (useFetch):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export const useFetch = (method: string, url: string, body: any) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);
  const [serverError, setServerError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log('~~ fetchData ~~');
    try {
      console.log('~~ fetchData - try ~~');
      const res = await axios({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: body,
      });
      console.log('~~ fetchData - res ~~');
      console.log(res);
      const data = await res?.data;
      console.log('~~ setApiData - useState ~~');
      console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
      setApiData(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error: any | unknown) {
      setServerError(error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [url, method, body]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return { isLoading, apiData, serverError };
};
```

Tab where fetch occurs:

```
export { useFetch } from '../../hooks/useFetch';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  const { isLoading, serverError, apiData } = useFetch(
    'GET',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    {}
  );
  }
```

Comment: Every time `TabTwoScreen` is rendering, you are passing a new object as the body. Use `useMemo(() => ({}), [])` or declare a constant outside of the component.

Comment: Remove useCallback and also remove fetchData from dependency array.

Comment: Thanks @TayyabMazhar. The dependency array issue was creating the loop. Is there a reason for the removal of `useCallback` isn't this a good function to use to cache the data so the API call isn't occurring each time the tab is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your useEffect triggers everytime `fetchData` changes. With the code example you've provided it seems to change every render because `body` is included in its dependency. Since `body` is an object, will be a new dependency every render causing `fetchData` to be recreated and `useEffect` to run again.

To fix this you can try a already posted answer below your post, by using useMemo, or remove the body from the dependency array and try to refactor your code a bit.